# BASH script not reading input mysql password

Tags: mysql, bash, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute Mysql command from a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055694/how-to-execute-mysql-command-from-a-shell-script)

I'm trying to execute a `.sql` file using a bash script. But I am having a problem connecting to MySQL. Here's what I have so far:

```
#! /bin/sh
PWD="thepassword"
mysql -p -u theuser < Randomsqlfile.sql
echo $PWD
```

When the password is prompted, nothing fills out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make this:

```
mysql -utheuser -pthepassword <Randomsqlfile.sql
```