# avoid asking second time mysql root password (bash)

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

In a simple script like this one:

```
set -x
# Check if db exists, if not we make it, make user, give privileges
if ! mysql -u root -p -e "use $db" 2>/dev/null; then

    c1="CREATE DATABASE $db"
    c2="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${db}.* to '$username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$password'"
    c3="FLUSH PRIVILEGES"

    mysql -u root -p -e "$c1; $c2; $c3"
else
    echo 'DATABASE ExISTS, ABORTING'; exit $DB_EXISTS
fi
```

I am asked each time, bash sees `mysql` command, for my root credentials.
Is there a way to avoid that, so that once entered the root password, all
additional mysql commands execute seamlessly?

Comment: You can ask for password, store it in a separate variable and pass it in the command as: `mysql --password $pass_var`

Answer (score 4):

Try looking into adding password to ~/.my.cnf

```
[client]
user = root
password = XXXXXXXX
```

Check out :

[How to execute a MySQL command from a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055694/how-to-execute-a-mysql-command-from-a-shell-script)

Comment: There's also a very poorly-documented flag that allows you to specify a particular file: `mysql --defaults-extra-file=/path/to/.my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the **--password** argument

```
mysql -u root --password=my_mysql_pass db_name
```

Safer using a bash variable

```
mysql -u root --password=$MYSQL_PASS db_name
```