# How to execute a MySQL command using shell script from PHP page?

Tags: php, mysql, bash, shell

I want to execute a shell script from php page which will execute a MySQL command.

To do this I followed the way shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055745/2117868

Here is my `sqlscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo wget -t 50 -O /tmp/update.sql http://example.com/update.sql
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    mysql -h "localhost" -u "root" "-pXXXXXXXX" "database-name" < "/tmp/update.sql"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        sudo rm /tmp/update.sql
        echo "200"
    else
        echo "502"
    fi
else
    echo "404"
fi
```

And my php page is `runscript.php`

```
<?php
    shell_exec("sudo /path/to/script/sqlscript.sh");
?>
```

Now, when I'm calling the `sqlscript.sh` from the **server console** or **php page** `runscript.php` it works perfectly and returns `200` as expected.

But when I take MYSQL user and password in `~/.my.cnf` so I don't have to put it on the command-line at all:

```
[client]
user = root
password = XXXXXXXX
```

And added credentials in `sudoer` to execute this script without password.

```
User_Alias WWW_USER = www-data
Cmnd_Alias WWW_COMMANDS_SQL = /path/to/script/sqlscript.sh
WWW_USER ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: WWW_COMMANDS_SQL
```

Here is my `sqlscript.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo wget -t 50 -O /tmp/update.sql http://example.com/update.sql
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    mysql -h "localhost" "database-name" < "/tmp/update.sql"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        sudo rm /tmp/update.sql
        echo "200"
    else
        echo "502"
    fi
else
    echo "404"
fi
```

Now, when I'm calling the `sqlscript.sh` from the **server console** it works perfectly and returns `200` as expected. But if I call it from the php page

```
http://example.com/runscript.php
```

it returns `502` as it couldn't execute the SQL command.

**Update:**

Here is the Apache `error.log`

```
--2014-12-05 10:51:55--  http://example.com/update.sql
Resolving example.com (example.com)... 162.144.71.XXX
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|162.144.71.XXX|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 146 [text/x-sql]
Saving to: `/tmp/update.sql'

     0K                                                       100% 10.9M=0s

2014-12-05 10:51:55 (10.9 MB/s) - `/tmp/update.sql' saved [146/146]

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

So, please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: This is probably a permission issue. you're running php with web server user, and in console with a different user. to analyze the problem you should check apache logs, and see (maybe also edit your question with it) the exact error message.

Comment: still, check the error.log, believe me it helps.

Comment: This is clearly a permission issue. The user who executes the PHP script and therefore your bash script (and mysql), is not allowed to access my.cnf file.

Comment: Hi, @VolkanUlukut thanks for you support. I updated the question adding the Apache error log. But why this script is causing this permission error?

Comment: You don’t need root privileges for the commands you are executing.

Comment: Do you mean I should change the php page to 
    `<?php
    shell_exec("/path/to/script/sqlscript.sh");
    ?>`  
I changed the php page as explained and got `404`

Comment: @kuttumiah show here your `.my.cnf` file permissions (`ls -lahZ ~/.my.cnf`). As you're running PHP with Apache, who is calling your bash script is the `www-data` (or `apache`) user: is it allowed to read `.my.cnf` file?

Comment: Here is the permission scenario of `.my.cnf`  


`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root ? 55 Dec  5 10:28 /home/user/.my.cnf`

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding the **--defaults-extra-file** option.
`mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/.my.cnf` ...

Or with absolute path (*might be required via apache, depends on server config*):
`mysql --defaults-extra-file=/absolute/path/to/.my.cnf` ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

In your shell script, instead of

```
mysql -h "localhost" "database-name" < "/tmp/update.sql"
```

use

```
mysql -h "localhost"-u root -ppassword "database-name" < "/tmp/update.sql"
```

Basically, try to pass MySQL username and password inside your shell script. Of course you can put them into variables/configs/whatever to obsecure it

MySQL 28000 error showed that your script was able to attempt to login as a root but because there was no parameter password, it failed

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I've tried it. And it's at the beginning of my question that this way is working. But I don't want to write password directly in the script. That's what I wanted.

Comment: Apologies for not reading the question properly. For some reason I mis-read the original script. Have you tried to either put `.my.cnf` into www-data home folder instead of your user's home folder? Alternatively set the apache user into your user (which arguably not preferred by some people)