# how to execute mysql command using script shell

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I want to execute mysql command using shell scripting in centos i am writing command over can anyone please tell me how to write this script and i am taking output in file so everytime when i execute script it create new file .

```
SELECT TABLENAME, tablerow, round(data_length/1024/1024 ,2 ) as dl , round(index_length/1024/1024 ,2 ) as il , round(data_length/1024/1024 ,2 ) as dl , round((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024 ,2)  "size in mb" from Information schema , TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=" Db_name" order by data_length desc limit 10 in to out file ' ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' | ' ENCLOSED BY "  " TERMINATED BY '\R\N '
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute a MySQL command from a shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055694/how-to-execute-a-mysql-command-from-a-shell-script)

Comment: no its not duplicate i want to run command as well to change output file everytime when its executes

Comment: One of the answers there tells you how to write the output to a file.

Comment: If you want a different file name you need some kind of counter or a time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
mysql -u username -pPassword <database> -e "SELECT TABLENAME, tablerow, round(data_length/1024/1024 ,2 ) as dl , round(index_length/1024/1024 ,2 ) as il , round(data_length/1024/1024 ,2 ) as dl , round((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024 ,2)  "size in mb" from Information schema , TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=" Db_name" order by data_length desc limit 10 in to out file ' ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' | ' ENCLOSED BY "  " TERMINATED BY '\R\N ';"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u root -p <Hit enter>
root             <Here root is password>

show databases;
```

See databases first and then select.

```
use database YourDatabase
```

Then enter your command like :

```
>SELECT TABLENAME, tablerow, round(data_length/1024/1024 ,2 ) as dl , round(index_length/1024/1024 ,2 ) as il , round(data_length/1024/1024 ,2 ) as dl , round((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024 ,2)  "size in mb" from Information schema , TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=" Db_name" order by data_length desc limit 10 in to out file ' ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' | ' ENCLOSED BY "  " TERMINATED BY '\R\N '
```