# Executing mutiple MySQL Queries in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I need to run a monthly bash script via cron that is related to our company's billing system.  This is done with two stored procedures.  When I run them via the MySQL console and workbench, they work fine.

I've looked at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055694/how-to-execute-a-mysql-command-from-a-shell-script) and this is basically the way I do it.

I call via cron, a shell script that looks like this:

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.1 -u<username> -p<password> mydatabase < /path/to/billing_periods.sql
```

My text file that has the commands in it looks like this:

```
call sp_start_billing_period();
call sp_bill_clients();
```

What happens is that the first query runs, but the second one on the second line, doesn't.

I can make a stored procedure that wraps these two - but I just was hoping to learn why this was happening... Perhaps a mistake I made or a limit in the way you do this..

I also considered doing this (two calls to the MySQL shell):

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.1 -u<username> -p<password> mydatabase -e "call sp_start_billing_period();"

mysql -h 192.168.1.1 -u<username> -p<password> mydatabase -e "call sp_bill_clients();"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try separating each statement with a semicolon.

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.1 -u<username> -p<password> mydatabase -e "call sp_start_billing_period();call sp_bill_clients();"
```

If you have your statements in a file you can do:

```
while read LINE; do mysql -u<username> -p<password> mydatabase -e"$LINE";echo "-----------";done < statements.sql
```

Comment: I am very late in my response, I apologize. Your suggestion worked perfectly; thank you! –

Answer (score 0):

I think you are only allowed to execute a single statement in your input .sql file, see the mysql documentation (manpage) for -e statement.

> ```
> Â·   --execute=statement, -e statement
>       Execute the statement and quit. The default output format is like that produced with --batch.
> ```

The -e is implicit. At least when I do different mysql queries I put them in their own script like you already suggested.