# How do I run a sql query using shell script for mysql server. I am new to shell scripting.

Tags: mysql, sql, shell

Server : MySQL
Query : SQL
Requirement : Shell Script

How do I run a sql query using shell script for mysql server.
This will help me in automating the task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a MySQL command from a shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055694/how-to-execute-a-mysql-command-from-a-shell-script)

Comment: I have to output of this query in an Excel File. What more do I add to this query?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u USER -p PASSWORD -h MYSQLSERVERNAME -e 'select * from foo...' database-name
```

Comment: I have to output of this query in an Excel File. What more do I add to this query?