# How do I call a MySQL stored procedure, on Linux, from a Windows batch script

Tags: mysql, linux, database

I can call sp when MySQL is on a Windows box but I'm not familiar with Linux so I don't have a clue. Thanks for your help

Comment: you need to convert `.bat` to `.sh` ...

Comment: so .sh on windows is going to run the stored proc on the Linux box?

Comment: you cannot run batch on Linux, because there is no such thing, there only is shell script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055694/how-to-execute-a-mysql-command-from-a-shell-script