# MariaDB --init-command when invoking mysql from a BASH script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, mariadb

I am a new user on Stack Overflow, so I apologize in advance for any potential breaches of site etiquette.

I am attempting to create a BASH script that will generate a command to invoke the MariaDB monitor, i.e. `mysql`.  I want this `mysql` command to include the `--init-command` option.  I want the `--init-command` option to set a list of user variables to a their values, as specified in a configuration file.

The script builds a string that appears to be correct for my purpose but, when it invokes `mysql`, an error is generated.  If I print out the generated string from the script, it appears to be exactly what I was attempting to create.

I have boiled it down to the following code example:

```
#!/bin/sh
declare foo="name"
declare bar="value"
declare invoke="mysql -p -D information_schema"
declare opts=" --init-command='SET @$foo:=\"$bar\"'"
invoke+=$opts
echo $invoke
$invoke
```

When I execute this script, the result looks like:

```
$ example.sh
mysql -p -D information_schema --init-command='SET @name:="value"'
Enter password:
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'Bill'@'%' to database '@name:="value"''
```

This error message doesn't even seem to make sense.

However, if I copy the generated command, and paste it back into the command prompt, it requests my password, and proceeds as I would expect, as follows:

```
$ mysql -p -D information_schema --init-command='SET @name:="value"'
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 171
Server version: 10.3.11-MariaDB Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [information_schema]> SELECT @name;
+-------+
| @name |
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [information_schema]>
```

Demonstrating that the `SET` command in the `--init-command` option was successfully passed to the MariaDB monitor, and executed.

I do not know whether this is a Linux issue, a BASH issue, or a MariaDB issue.  So, while I have spent a good amount of time trying to find the answer, I really don't know where the problem originates, and therefore, where to focus my research.

Please note: I only used the information_schema database in my example because I expect that anyone attempting to recreate this problem would have that database available to them.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Well-constructed first post!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055694/how-to-execute-a-mysql-command-from-a-shell-script for how to call mysql from within a script.  You cannot interact with mysql once in the script (hence no password is given).

Comment: Thank you, squareskittles.  I have benefitted from reading many S.O. threads.  So, I tried to be thorough, clear, and follow the examples I have read in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

Option 1:

```
#!/bin/sh

# USING BASH
# FILE: bash_mariadb.sh

foo="\`name\`"
bar="value"

mysql -p -D information_schema --init-command="SET @$foo:='$bar';"
```

Option 2:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# USING BASH
# FILE: bash_mariadb.sh

foo="\`name\`"
bar="value"

opts=(--init-command="SET @$foo:='$bar';")
invoke=(mysql -p -D information_schema "$opts")
"${invoke[@]}"
```

Option 3:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# USING BASH
# FILE: bash_mariadb.sh

foo="\`name\`"
bar="value"

#define
invoke() {
  opts=(--init-command="SET @$foo:='$bar'")

  if [[ -v opts ]]; then
    invoke=(mysql -p -D information_schema "$opts")
  else
    invoke=(mysql -p -D information_schema)
  fi

  "${invoke[@]}"
}

#call
invoke
```

Option 4: DANGER, option not recommended for safety reasons.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# USING BASH
# FILE: bash_mariadb.sh

foo="\`name\`"
bar="value"

invoke="mysql -p -D information_schema"
opts=" --init-command='SET @$foo:=\"$bar\"'"
invoke+=$opts
eval $invoke
```

In all cases:

```sh
$ ./bash_mariadb.sh
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 1
Server version: 10.3.11-MariaDB Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [information_schema]> SELECT @`name`;
+---------+
| @`name` |
+---------+
| value   |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, for both the encouragement and the answers.

Comment: Your answer was enlightening, and incredibly thorough.  At this point, I have gotten my scrip to work, using the 'dangerous' eval method.  I shall continue to work on it, and try to eliminate the eval.  In any case, you got me back on track and I sincerely thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

From a script you have to indicate the password you want to use.

The option `-p` force it for a interactive introduction of the password, wich don't works from a script.

If you instead use `-ppassword` (notice that you still write the "p", only that you write it next to the password, without spaces), your connection will work.

So, you just have to modify the line:

`declare invoke="mysql -ppassword -D information_schema"`

(Don't forget to write your password where I wrote "password", of course :) )