# Executing a sql query multiple times in MySQL similar to GO in TSQL(SQL Server)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run the below command in MySQL multiple times. Is there an easy way like the GO command in TSQL/SQL Server for MySQL?

```
select
  now(),
  @@max_connections as "Max Connections",
  count(host) as "Current Connections"
from information_schema.processlist;
```

Wanted to keep it simple for a demo. Not looking for a SPROC.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple times?" The easiest way would be to write a stored procedure.

Comment: I wanted to run the above command 100 times for a demo and show the query running via the command line utility.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> set @query = 'select
    '>   now(),
    '>   @@max_connections as "Max Connections",
    '>   count(host) as "Current Connections"
    '> from information_schema.processlist; ';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> prepare stmt from @query;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> execute stmt;
+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| now()               | Max Connections | Current Connections |
+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 2021-08-16 18:22:03 |             512 |                   1 |
+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Then you can `execute stmt` as many times as you want in the same session (prepared statements have a scope of the current session).

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html for more information.

Comment: Thank you Bill. This is helpful. How do I run the execute stmt like 100 times in loop without involvement? With SQL Server/TSQL, the GO command lets you do that easily. Like SELECT * FROM table GO 100; This will run the SELECT statement 100 times.

Comment: I'd write a script in Python.

Comment: Depending on your OS you could write a shell script with a loop that repeatedly executes something like `mysql <query.sql`, where `query.sql` is a textfile containing the SQL query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055694/how-to-execute-a-mysql-command-from-a-shell-script/8055745